# Reading semicolon delimited string value from ini file

Tags: php

I am reading configuration file, I want to read a name which contains `;` in string like

```
config=node1;node2;node3
```

i want to read as a whole instead of `node1` as replied by php in reading

my code:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("test_config.conf", true);
$nodelist = $ini_array["config"];
```

Comment: Change your ini file entry to `config="node1;node2;node3"`

Comment: change the semicolon with comma, semicolon are used as comment

Comment: Same file is using by servers time to time to read configurations, and i am trying to read it in php which includes `;` and it makes me cry :p

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker but i can not make any edit in config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `;` indicates a comment in an ini file, `parse_ini_file()` will correctly throw away everything behind a (non quoted) `;`.

For me it looks like you are misusing the `ini` format, thus if you want to obtain that information, you need to parse the file on your own, like this:

```
$config = array();
foreach(file('/path/to/conf.ini') as $line) {
    if(preg_match('/^([^;]*?)=(.*)/', $line, $m)) {
        $config[$m[1]] = $m[2];
    }
}

var_dump($config);
```

If you only need the value of `config`, you can use this:

```
preg_match('/^\s*config\s*=(.*)/', file_get_contents('config.ini'), $m);
echo $config = $m[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I am new to php it gives me all details in php but i want to read that string only value of config

Comment: it says  Undefined offset: 1

Comment: The entry is config=node1;node2;node3 and i am reading other values correct, it means file is opened and reading correct but this entry throws an error Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Your file contains only one line?

Comment: Sorry @hek2mgl confidential document
Done thank you, i convert it in array and read it by finding string

Comment: Ok. I still don't get what is the problem. You can use the first example and then access: `echo $config['config'];`